# Do while emulation in python is not working properly

Tags: python, json, web-services, azure-devops-rest-api

```
testurl = '{}/testplan/Plans/{}/Suites/{}/Testpoint?includePointDetails=true&api-version=5.1-preview.2'.format(base, planId, suiteId)

print(testurl)

while True:
    c = count_testpoints(testplanAPI(base, planId, suiteId, callAPI(testurl)))
   if(c<200):
        break
```

Where callAPI() is a function is used to return a header from the response which is passed as an argument to testplanAPI() to build a new testurl using that argument as URL parameter. testplanAPI() returns testurl while count_testpoints() returns the count of testpoints.

I have to close the loops after its get the first count less than 200.

Using above code is building the url only once and iterating the same condition infinitely. It's not appending the url further after the first iteration.

Can you please suggest a better way or what can be rectify here?

Comment: Put the `testurl = ...` line *into* the `while` loop and modify it as needed…!? Yes, of course, with your current code the URL is only constructed once before the loop.

Comment: Donot know how the methods In above code is implemented. I hope i am wrong But i render callAPI(testurl) always returns the same value. So parameters `base, planId, suiteId, callAPI(testurl)` is the same for testplanAPI() for very loop. And i thought it is the reason above code binding url only once.

Comment: @django How did it go with this case? Any updates?

Answer (score 0):

As @deceze correctly wrote, you have to set the url inside the loop, and you most likely have to save the new base and IDs...

```py
while c < 200:
    testurl = '{}/testplan/Plans/{}/Suites/{}/Testpoint?includePointDetails=true&api-version=5.1-preview.2.format(base, planId, suiteId)'
    print(testurl)

    c = count_testpoints(testplanAPI(base, planId, suiteId, callAPI(testurl)))
    # sth like: base, planId, suiteId = new values for these...
```

Comment: Actually the first testurl doesn't have the url parameter returned by callAPI() function. Only after the first testurl is called we need to take the header ms continuation token and then we have to build another testurl but with continuation Token as parameter and then we have to call the API then we have to check count. If count is 200 (which is the payload limit of the API) then we have to take the header token from this testurl and have to build another till the count comes less than 200.

Comment: then change the while loop back, I can't check if it still works. But the testurl has to be inside the loop...